# Regex to match words

Tags: .net, regex

I'm looking for a Regex (using .NET) to match the word ass. The Regex shouldn't match words like assignment.

How can I do this?

Comment: changed tags; C# doesn't support regex ***at all*** - the .NET BCL, however, does

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex match entire words only](/q/1751301/90527)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for word boundaries (`\b`):

```
\bass\b
```

This will match `ass` but not `bass` or `assignment`.

Comment: And, since this is C# (although @Marc removed that tag), take care to use verbatim strings: `@"\bass\b"`. If you forget the `@`, the `\b` means backspace.

Answer (score 1):

How about `\bass\b` ? This uses word boundaries to limit it to the single word.

Answer (score 1):

Most modern regular expression engines support the `\b` anchor, meaning a zero-width word boundary.

See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) for some examples using that (and other) anchor characters.

Answer (score 1):

Visit this page for full manual [Word Boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you?

```
\bass\b
```

Answer (score 0):

\b(ass)\b or \bass\b should be good.