# Regex.Replace to complete words 

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regex to match words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5974753/regex-to-match-words)
>   [Way to have String.Replace only hit “whole words”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143642/way-to-have-string-replace-only-hit-whole-words)

I need do a simple regex.replace() on text with complete words.

Example: 
pattern to find: "kiss"
word replace: "metallica"

text 1:
Kiss is the rock band.
Metallica is the rock band. (OK)

text 2:
The boy kissed the girl.
The boy metallicaed the girl. (ERROR)

I need find the exactly the same word, maybe verifying the white space before and after the word... I don't know :(

I think this is easy to do but I'm not finding the solution.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Use the word boundary escape `\b`:

```
@"\bkiss\b"
```

[RegularExpressions.Info reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html).

Make sure to use the ignore case option.

Answer (score 0):

for this use word boundaries `\b`

```
@"\bKiss\b"
```

will match only the word "Kiss" and not "kissed"

`\b` matches on the change from a word character to a non word character.

`\w` contains word  characters that means all letters, digits and _

Examples:

Will match on:

> Kiss, Kiss123, Kiss Kiss. Kiss@ Kiss_

Will not match on (if ignore case is used):

> kissed Kisses

Comment: Is it possible to replace only 1 time? On the first occurrence of word.

Comment: There exist a [very good manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6f7hht7k.aspx). You need [Regex.Replace Method (String, String, Int32, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3fky5t5f.aspx), where you can specify in the 3 parameter how many replacements you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use this regular expression:

```
(?i)\bkiss\b
```

with word boundaries and ignore-case option.

Answer (score 0):

ahh i think i get what you mean. my regex is terrible but bear with me...

try 
`(test)*`

where test is the word you want to replace?

that matches testing, testy, testicles etc

Comment: I don't think that you understood what the OP meant.